# Add a pause on hover of slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, mouseover

Hi I'm trying to add a pause to a slideshow that i have.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slides').superslides({
    slide_easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
    slide_speed: 900,
    pagination: true,
    hashchange: true,
    scrollable: true,
    pagination: false,
    play:6000
  });
});
```

what do i add to make the slideshow pause on mouseover

Comment: Isn't SuperSlides a full screen slideshow?

Comment: Uhmm. [jQuery delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) helps? `$('#slides').delay(3000).superslides(`

Comment: If you are using a fullscreen slider, you're going to have to go into more detail on exactly what element the mouseover event triggers the pause / unpause. Because surely, you don't want the whole slider to have a hover > pause action as you will never get to slide 2 unless your mouse is not on the page! I guess the best option is to pause when you over over a div on a slide?

Comment: here is the slider @Adam http://TiffanyEvansOfficial.com only when i hover of the slider should it pause

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you even found the answer to your question. However there is a an API call in the [Github documentation](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides#api) for superslides. To implement this you might do something like:

```
$('#slides').on('mouseenter', function() { $(this).superslides('stop'); });
```

and on leaving the hover:

```
$('#slides').on('mouseleave', function() { $(this).superslides('start'); });
```

If this helps, please let me know!